# WSO2 password reset error

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

Tried to reset the admin password for WSO2 Identity server and API manager, following instructions for [API Manager](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Maintaining+Logins+and+Passwords) and [Identity server](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Configuring+the+System+Administrator)

but now the old applications are not being listed and in the wso2 carbon logs for  identity server it shows "Illegal access attempt at from IP address while trying to authenticate access to service APIKeyValidationService". Any advice on how to debug the issue?

Comment: Did you update admin credentials in `user-mgt.xml`?

Comment: yes I updated the password field in both user-mtg.xml files